# 「golang programs」というチュートリアルサイトの「Variadic Functions」に関する段落が理解できない

Tags: go

[Select single argument from all arguments of variadic function.](https://www.golangprograms.com/go-language/variadic-functions.html) セクションにある、次のパラグラフの意味が分かる方、ご教示願えれば幸いです。

> Needs to be precise when running an empty function call, if the code inside of the function expecting an argument and absence of argument will generate an error "panic: run-time error: index out of range". In above example you have to pass at least 4 arguments.

問題は、最初のセンテンスです。In above ... は自明です。
an empty function call とは、「引数を与えない関数呼び出し」の意味だろうと思います。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

それでは実際に実行してみましょう。

https://go.dev/play/p/omWI1XFl5RE

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    variadicExample()
}

func variadicExample(s ...string) {
    fmt.Println(s[0])
    fmt.Println(s[3])
}
```

**実行結果**

```golang
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.variadicExample({0x0, 0x485320, 0xc0000001a0})
    /tmp/sandbox399561776/prog.go:10 +0xef
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox399561776/prog.go:6 +0x25

Program exited.
```

Answer (score 0):

まず、サンプルコードには、このように書かれています。
variadicExample は、可変長引数受け取れるようになっていますが、実装は、1つ目と4つ目の引数の値を標準出力に表示する処理になっています。

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    variadicExample("red", "blue", "green", "yellow")
}

func variadicExample(s ...string) {
    fmt.Println(s[0])
    fmt.Println(s[3])
}
```

質問戻りますが、メソッドのインプットでは、可変長引数になっているのに実装は最低限４つの引数が必要となっているため、例えばひとつもパラメータを与えないと panic を起こしますということが書かれています。
※例としてひとつもパラメータをケースが書かれていますが、実装を見る限り２つないし、3つでもpanicは発生します

> Needs to be precise when running an empty function call, if the code inside of the function expecting an argument and absence of argument will generate an error "panic: run-time error: index out of range". In above example you have to pass at least 4 arguments.